# jQuery Table manipulation

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

Trying to manipulate a table with jQuery, and I just cannot seem to get it to work properly.
The empty works just fine, but I cannot add content back onto the table after.

Any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong?

```
<table id="schedualtable">
    <tbody id="sortable">
        <tr><td></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

$('#schedualtable > tbody:last').empty().append($.get('incl/ajax_category.php?action=filtercat', {'cata': $('#filtercat').val()}));

$('#sortable').empty().append($.get('incl/ajax_category.php?action=filtercat', {'cata': $('#filtercat').val()}));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) you should use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), like this:

```
$('#sortable').load('incl/ajax_category.php?action=filtercat', 
                    {'cata': $('#filtercat').val()});
```

[`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) doesn't return the data, it's available in it's callback method though.  [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) actually takes the result and puts it in that element.

For the [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method, it'd look like this:

```
$.get('incl/ajax_category.php?action=filtercat', {'cata': $('#filtercat').val()},
      function(data) { $('#sortable').html(data); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you want to use `.html()` instead of `.append()` since you are putting the content inside and then you don't need to `.empty()` as well?

Comment: In this case that's not the main issue, [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) returns an `XmlHttpRequest` object, not the actual result/string (it's an async operation), so the content going into the `.html()` or `.append()` methods wouldn't be useful.

Comment: Tried html first. Sorry, didn't include in the post.